# MySQL syntax for create table from select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a permanent subset of a table using

```
create table copydata (select a.* from tabla a
         left join table b 
         on st_distance(a.point, b.point) <= 10
         and b.x is null)
```

this works but builds the table "copydata" as an InnoDB table. I need this to be an ISAM table so I can build the spatial indices. I've tried

```
create table copydata (select a.* from tablea a
         left join tableb b 
         on st_distance(a.point, b.point) <= 10
         and b.x is null) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

but this complains about a syntax error.

What am I missing?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order of the statements:

```
create table copydata ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 (select a.* from tablea a
         left join tableb b 
         on st_distance(a.point, b.point) <= 10
         and b.x is null)
```